# ${}$Reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

Most of the particles have different velocity in different reference of frames but why is speed of light the same in all refrence frames?  After all light is made of a photon.

Comment: Because we observed it that way experimentally

Comment: a photon is not an object. It is a discrete packet/quantum of EM radiation with energy proportional to the frequency

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that we don't know why $c$ is constant. It is one of the postulates of special relativity:

> The speed of light in vacuum is the same for all observers, regardless of the motion of the light source or observer.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity))

Both special relativity and the constant speed of light have been experimentally verified which leads to the conclusion that $c$ is indeed constant. However, there is no known underlying cause for this.